# I am unable to combine Numpy arrays in ArcMap when using FeatureClassToNumPyArray

Tags: arcmap, numpy

I am using FeatureClasstoNumPyArray to get information from two features classes

```
import arcpy
import numpy

sspipe_fcs = 'ssGravityMain'
sspipe_fl = ('ORIGINAL_COST', 'FEATURE', 'DEVELOPMENT','LENGTH_M4')
ssarr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(sspipe_fcs, sspipe_fl)
print ssarr
print ssarr.shape
print ssarr.dtype   

wlpipe_fcs = 'Water Mains'
wlpipe_fl = ('ORIGINAL_COST', 'FEATURE', 'DEVELOPMENT','Shape_Length')
wlarr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(wlpipe_fcs, wlpipe_fl)
print wlarr
print wlarr.shape
print wlarr.dtype

numpy.concatenate ((ssarr, wlarr))
```

I would like to combine both arrays but I get an error

```
TypeError: invalid type promotion
```

My overall goal is to use the array to eventually prepare some type of pivot table using pandas.

Here are the results of those print statements

```
[(3087.622879285057, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 90.81243762603108)
 (4308.758177145577, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 126.72818168075227)
 (2079.15277816955, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 61.15155229910441)
 (2055.8024028091863, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 60.464776553211365)
 (3825.8261621564598, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 112.5242988869547)
 (5056.951172625341, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 148.7338580183924)
 (4143.872612491386, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 121.87860624974664)
 (4545.80563630292, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 133.70016577361528)
 (3010.085501040413, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 88.53192650118862)
 (3139.2163487103285, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 92.32989260912731)
 (3251.2079792976815, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 95.62376409699063)
 (2104.7324983994613, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 61.90389701174887)
 (2894.457469764144, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 85.1311020518866)
 (1922.1176673586654, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 56.53287256937251)
 (3746.678222477405, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 110.19641830815897)
 (2629.9600545841795, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 77.3517663112994)
 (7509.473519849657, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 220.86686823087229)
 (4927.328877910251, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 144.92143758559564)
 (5740.15444723423, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 168.82807197747735)]
(19,)
[('ORIGINAL_COST', '<f8'), ('FEATURE', '<U50'), ('DEVELOPMENT', '<U50'), ('LENGTH_M4', '<f8')]
[(28937.625507077002, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 826.7893002022)
 (11969.306667602146, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 341.98019050291845)
 (21051.785700918437, u'Pipe', u'shopping center', 601.4795914548125)]
(3,)
[('ORIGINAL_COST', '<f8'), ('FEATURE', '<U10'), ('DEVELOPMENT', '<U50'), ('Shape_Length', '<f8')]
```

Comment: I believe it has something to do with the `dtypes` of the arrays not coinciding. Can you show us what `ssarr.dtype` and `wlarr.dtype` are?

Comment: @MarceloVilla I have updated my post with that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot concatenate the two arrays because of two reasons:

- `dtype` for `FEATURE` is different (`<U50` vs. `<U10`).
- The fourth field name is different (`LENGTH_M4` vs. `Shape_Length`)

You said you wanted to eventually prepare some pivot table using `pandas` so here is one approach that creates a `DataFrame` from each array, renames the columns of the second array and then concatenates both `DataFrames` into a third one:

```py
import arcpy
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# get first array
sspipe_fcs = 'ssGravityMain'
sspipe_fl = ('ORIGINAL_COST', 'FEATURE', 'DEVELOPMENT','LENGTH_M4')
ssarr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(sspipe_fcs, sspipe_fl)

# get second array
wlpipe_fcs = 'Water Mains'
wlpipe_fl = ('ORIGINAL_COST', 'FEATURE', 'DEVELOPMENT','Shape_Length')
wlarr = arcpy.da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(wlpipe_fcs, wlpipe_fl)

# convert arrays to DataFrames
dfss = pd.DataFrame(ssarr)
dfwl = pd.DataFrame(wlarr)

# match column names (Shape_Length will become LENGTH_M4)
dfwl.columns = dfss.columns

# create a new concatenated array
df = pd.concat([dfss, dfwl], ignore_index=True)

# check result
df.head()

   ORIGINAL_COST FEATURE      DEVELOPMENT   LENGTH_M4
0    3087.622879    Pipe  shopping center   90.812438
1    4308.758177    Pipe  shopping center  126.728182
2    2079.152778    Pipe  shopping center   61.151552
3    2055.802403    Pipe  shopping center   60.464777
4    3825.826162    Pipe  shopping center  112.524299
```